# Only one backslash in javascript

Tags: javascript, backslash

I know that backslash is escape character in js. And to display one backslash, I need to write two.

But I am having express server that send request to database and here I need to add only one backslash. SO if filter contains two backslashes, replace it only with one. How to write it?

```
     filter.replace("\\", String.fromCharCode(92)); //do two not one
     filter.replace("\\", "\"); //doesn't work, syntax error
```

example
        "aaaa\\aaaa" - > "aaaa\aaaa"

Another ideas?
---UPADTE---
The string that is send to database contains two backslashes but js GUI shows only one (of course).

Comment: `"\"` is a syntax error. As you stated, if you want a literal backslash in a string, you need to write *two* of them. `"\\"` is a single backslash. `"\\\\"` is *two* backslashes.

Answer (score 2):

> How to write it?

You said it yourself:

> to display one backslash, I need to write two.

So, if you have two in the string to start with, then you need to replace two (type four) with one (type two).

```js
var filter = "This string has a double slash in it: \\\\";
console.log(`The original string: ${filter}`);
filter = filter.replace("\\\\", "\\");
console.log(`The filtered string: ${filter}`);
```

Comment: Yes, but the string that is send to database contains still two backslashes. GUI shows only one of course.

Comment: @13Akaren — Then something is adding a second backslash to it *after* the end of this code.

Answer (score 0):

Quentin answered your question, but another way to think about it is that two backslashes written into a sting will resolve to a single backslash as soon as you do anything with it.

For example:

```js
Console.Log("\");
//Returns Error

Console.Log("\\");
//Returns:  \

var i = "this is a backslash \\"
//i now contains only one backslash
Console.Log(i);
//Returns:  this is a backslash \
```

Edit:

Since you clarified that it's after this in the querying that it gets messed up, you could try making sure you've assigned it to a variable and then passed it to the query.

```js
i = "A string containing backslashes \\"
sql.Query(i);
```

Edit 2:

Oh, I just got it, you're trying to escape colons ':' which is already handled in JS. So if the query isn't parsing your escape characters than just `\:` should be perfectly valid.

Comment: As I wrote, but the string that is send to database contains still two backslashes. GUI shows only one of course. Database is not js so it will not remove one backslash...

Comment: As Quentin mentioned above, it sounds like we'd need to see the query function to know what's going on.

Comment: it's elasticserach database. To filter field I pass varialble "column: value" but value can contain sometimes colon so I need to place backshalsh in front of it.

Comment: You could try doing the replace inline with the query: `search('column: val\\:ue'.replace('\\\\', '\\'));`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have time to tested, I used your code but elasticsearh received still

{"query_string":{"query":"attrs.r-uri:sip\\:aaaaa"}}